# How to print longest and shortest word from text file story.txt and find the frequency of each of them in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, text

```
$string = file_get_contents('./story.txt', true); 

$words  = explode('\n', $string);
$w = array();

foreach ($words as $word) {
$temp = explode(' ', $word);
$w = array_merge($w, $temp);

}

$longestWordLength = 0;
$longestWord = '';

foreach ($w as $word) {
   if (strlen($word) > $longestWordLength) {
      $longestWordLength = strlen($word);
      $longestWord = $word;
   }
}

echo $longestWord;
echo strlen($longestWord);
```

I have written this code but it scans the ending word from one para and first word from next paragraph as same. In the following para:

> arts along the stream looks almost like a flash of sunlight.
>
> Desert animals are generally the color of the desert.

In this,

> sunlight. Desert

is treated as one word.

Comment: I thought first exploding by line and then exploding each exploded string by word would give me solution. But nothing happened :(

Comment: but why you need to explode it by line? you can easily explode it by word and trim your array if required

Comment: use `preg_spilt()`

Comment: You can use `str_word_count()` to get an array of words (without punctuation and newlines)

Comment: @AdityaShrivastava check my full answer below :) hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way to get the longest string from the file text, I've removed extra spaces and dot characters from the array using `array_map()`

```
function longest_string_in_array($array) {
    $array = array_map(function($item) { return trim($item, '. ');},$array);
    $mapping = array_combine($array, array_map('strlen', $array));
    return $mapping;
}

$string = file_get_contents('./story.txt', true);
$array = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $string );
print_r(longest_string_in_array($array));
```

Comment: thank you so much. But i wrote answer to my own post ;)

Comment: WC. no problem, glad it helps you somehow. best of luck

Comment: Can you also show me how to get smallest word form the string. I am not getting it.

Comment: Did you try `return array_keys($mapping, min($mapping));`?

Comment: I guess you'll easily able to find the longest and shortest if you use `return $mapping;` on that function because it has the word with the length count so it is easy to decide shortest and longest :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess the answer to this handsome boy's problem is that those words are not splitting apart that are separated by anything other than single whitespace. In this case the solution is to use,

```
$string = file_get_contents('./story.txt', true); 

$words   = preg_split('/\s+/', $string);
```

and you're good to go.